# Partitioning a string in Python

Tags: python, string, set

I had a string that was in the format:

```
name = '>n263590 | AK138667 | mRNAlike lncRNA |'
```

so when I wanted to partition it, I used the string:

```
name = name.partition(' |')[0]
```

---

I tried using the same concept for a string in the format:

```
name2 = '>mm10_refGene_NM_147038 range=chr1:92479681-92480629'
```

i want just the region that starts with 'NM' and up until the end of the digits

```
#i want the output to be name2 = 'NM_147038'
```

so I tried

```
name2 = name2.partition('NM','range')|[0]
```

but it didn't work

I think I know a way to do it using regex but it is not very memory efficient.
is there anyway I can use the partition tool to execute this?

Comment: Your syntax is far from correct, I am afraid. Did you actually read the [`.partition()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) documentation?

Comment: partition requires one argument but i was looking for a memory efficient way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

m = re.search(r"(NM_\d+)\s+range", name2)
if m:
   print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()`, it's a simple way to do the job. For example:

```
'NM' + name2.split('NM')[1]
=> 'NM_147038 range=chr1:92479681-92480629'
```

Or if there's only one delimiter, you can use the `index` function to create a new slice of the string:

```
name2[name2.index('NM'):]
=> 'NM_147038 range=chr1:92479681-92480629'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

re.findall(r'(NM_\d*)', name2)
```

Comment: the reason i was trying to avoid re.findall was because some cases there are strings where the NMddddd occurs again, but it is not separated followed by a ' range'

Comment: is there a way i can use re.search to make a similar construct ?

Comment: If you want to ensure it is followed by a `range`, use `(NM_\d*)(?= range)`.